# Do the DO-178 standards include guidelines on cyclomatic complexity?

Tags: avionics, software

Is there any guideline related to the cyclomatic complexity of software that complies with the DO-178C or DO-178B standards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer is No.

From the note after 5.2.2.g

> The current state of software engineering does not permit a quantitative
>   correlation between complexity and the attainment of system safety objectives.
>   While no objective guidance can be provided, the software design process should
>   avoid introducing complexity because as the complexity of software increases, it
>   becomes more difficult to verify the design and to show that the safety-related
>   requirements are satisfied.

DO-178C is focused on defining process objectives rather than design guidelines.  Your process (specifically Design Standards) might specify a certain maximum complexity value, but it wouldn't be driven directly from DO-178C